# once jquery event is passed to function, console.log($(this)); no longer prints jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsbin

When I attach a click even to some divs, I can print out `$(this)` in the Chrome console and I get the jquery object displayed there.

[image: console screenshot]
http://jsbin.com/iyozap/1/edit

However, I'm trying to get only the topmost dom node that is clicked. So I thought to use `stopPropagation()` in the function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '*', function(){
    console.log($(this));
  });
});
```

But whenever I pass the event into the function 
    `$('body').on('click', '*', function(event){`

I get `$(this)` printed to the console as `[object Object]`. Strange also that when I subsequently delete the `event` and the `event.stopPropagation()` from the function, the console still prints `[object Object]`.

I am simply trying to register a click on every part of the body except if it occurs on the div with the class `avoid`, but I seem not to be grasping the jquery `event` and its counterpart `stopPropagation()`. How does `$(this)` change from a jquery object that I can see inside of to just an `[object Object]` when `event` is passed in? How can I use it to only register clicks that don't occur within my `avoid` class?

Comment: For debugging objects, `console.dir` is sometimes better suited.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("body").on('click', '*' ...
```

delegates to *every* element.  I think you just want to do this:

```
$("body").on('click', '.avoid', function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
}).on('click', function () {
   console.log('body clicked');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/YZcP7/

Comment: This is indeed definitely what I was trying to do, thank you. What's the meaning of chaining the to `on()`s together? How does that work?

Comment: @thomas: It's the same as `$('body').on(...); $('body').on(...);` (i.e. calling `.on` on `body` twice). It works because `.on` is returning `this` (which refers to `$('body')`). The concept is called *fluent interface* through *method chaining*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining.

Comment: Bear in mind that stops propagation, if you did want propagation but  wanted to isolate the clicked element to log it for example `if (e.target==this) { console.log($(this)); }`

Comment: @popnoodles thank you. should that first `this` be `$(this)`? I can't seem to get it to do anything.

Comment: @thomas no, `e.target` would be equal to `this`

Comment: No, as Explosion also said, `this` like I said.

Comment: It doesn't seem to get it to do anything because you probably haven't added the e in `function()` to make it `function(e)`

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, you just needed to bind `stopPropagation()` to the specific event, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '*', function(e){
    console.log($(this));
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Where `e` is the event object. Works fine now. Here's an updated jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/iyozap/9/edit

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to indetify the clicked object too

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body > *').click(function(){
    console.log( $(this) );
  });
});
```